# Passing variable as add_shortcode argument

Tags: functions, shortcode

I'm trying to pass a variable into the add_shortcode function to be used as the shortcode name but it does not seem to be working. Is there a way that I can pass a variable similar to this?

```
foreach ($files1 as $value) {
    $new_value = substr($value, 0, -4);

    add_shortcode($new_value, function() {
        return '<img src="' . PATH . L_ITEMS . $new_value . '.gif">';
    });

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve and frankly, I honestly think that what you are trying is completely overrated. You somewhere have a big design flaw. If `$file1` has 100 values, you are going to create 100 shortcodes which you are going to use how?

Comment: Two keywords come to mind: `class` and `use`. But I wonder if you really need multiple shortcodes here, why not a single shortcode with an attribute?

Comment: Automatically searching through a directory of images and creating shortcodes based off of the files. The shortcodes are added to a dropdown menu that has been inserted into TinyMCE.

Comment: Not sure how I would achieve this using class and use.

Comment: Why then not just simply add the image directly from its name. That is exactly what your shortcode does. This is like visiting your neighbour, then walking all around the block to get to your house

Comment: One, there is a lot of images. This would save a decent amount of time. Two, adding an image to the directory would automatically create a shortcode for the image.

Comment: I second @Pieter's first comment. 1. Gigantic design flaw / ill formed architecture. 2. Go with *one* shortcode with an *attribute*.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what the people who use the shortcodes want. They'd rather have [item-name] than [item attr="item-name"]. I went ahead and wrote a script to do all of my work for me outside of PHP anyways. Why write 200 lines of code when you can write 5.

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions:

1. Use the [third argument for the shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/current-shortcode-detect-currently-used-shortcode).
2. Use the `use` keyword.

Examples

1. The third parameter for each shortcode callback is the name of the shortcode:

```php
foreach ($files1 as $value) {
    $new_value = substr($value, 0, -4);

    add_shortcode($new_value, function( $attributes, $content, $shortcode ) {
        return '<img src="' . PATH . L_ITEMS . $shortcode . '.gif">';
    });
}
```

2. Pass the variable you need to the `use` part of the lambda function:

```php
foreach ($files1 as $value) {
    $new_value = substr($value, 0, -4);

    add_shortcode($new_value, function() use ( $new_value ) {
        return '<img src="' . PATH . L_ITEMS . $new_value . '.gif">';
    });
}
```

I think you should register just one shortcode and pass the file as attribute value. That would be faster and easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, I'd upvote you if I could.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure your mind but I think parameter $new_value you are using in function add_shortcode is undefined.

Comment: $new_value is define just above the add_shortcode function. I'm having trouble passing the value of $new_value as an argument of add_shortcode though.

Comment: When printed out $new_value outputs the image name. I'm not understanding how it isn't defined.

Comment: @taido No it is not, it **is** defined. Please recheck

Comment: @user3232282 sorry about my comment, it was directed at taido. Unfortunately my comment to him came in after yours so the confusion was that it was directed at you telling you that your variable is not defined :-) I've corrected it now

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. I was a bit confused, haha.