# Can a shortcode return its own name?

Tags: shortcode

Assuming there is some function or variable that allows the shortcode access to its name, and for sake here I will term that `$scName`, is something like this possible:

```
function test_return_shortcode_name( $atts ) {
    return $scName;
}
add_shortcode( 'myName', 'test_return_shortcode_name' );
```

And so for this basic example, this shortcode:

```
[myName]
```

Which would return the actual name as text

```
myName
```

Does such functionality exist to access the designated name from *within* the function associated to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [current\_shortcode() - detect currently used shortcode](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42882/current-shortcode-detect-currently-used-shortcode)

Comment: @Milo Not closing as the question marked as duplicate has a very specific "workaround" instead of a real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shortcode can access its own name - it is supplied as third parameter to the shortcode's callback function, just like that:

```
function test_shortcode_callback( $atts = array(), $content = null, $tag ) {
    return $tag;
}
add_shortcode( 'test_shortcode', 'test_shortcode_callback' );

// So running this shortcode
[test_shortcode]
// Will return this
test_shortcode
```